# Javascript Hide Column by Default

Tags: javascript, html-table, show-hide

After browsing online for tutorials on Javascript show/hide I could only find examples on where all the columns were by default visible.  I'm looking for a way to have some columns hidden by default (and allow them to be toggled on via a checkbox) and to have some columns shown by default (and allow them to be toggled off via a checkbox).

Is this possible?

For reference my table structure is as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Job</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>Dancer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please find my ans with detailed example. It is done using jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure javascript:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showhide(1, this)" checked="checked" /> Name<br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showhide(3, this)" checked="checked" /> Job<br />
```

**JS**

```
function showhide(column, elem){
    if (elem.checked)
        dp = "table-cell";
    else
        dp = "none";
    tds = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i=0; i<tds.length; i++)
        tds[i].childNodes[column].style.display = dp;
}
```

**[Pure JS fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NPHDE/3/)**

Please consider using a javascript library as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for such trivial things. You code could be as simple as:

​
**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" data-col="1" checked="checked" /> Name<br />
<input type="checkbox" data-col="2" checked="checked" /> Job<br />
```

**jQuery JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
        $('th, td', 'tr').filter(':nth-child(' + $(this).data('col') + ')').toggle();
    });
});
```

**[jQuery Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FNfpA/9/)**

Comment: This is much less code however how do I hide columns by default?  Your example shows all the columns shown by default.

Comment: With jQuery or pure JS? Either way, you'd just have to start with the checkboxes unchecked and hide the columns which you want to hide in the body's `onload` (pure JS) or `$(document).ready()` (jQuery). Here's the [jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/FNfpA/5/) and the [Pure JS](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/NPHDE/4/) one. I've added some comments to those too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the toggle function (using jQuery):

```
function toggleColumns(column, state) {
    var cells = $("table").find("th, td").filter(":nth-child(" + column + ")");

    if (state)
        cells.hide();
    else
        cells.show();
}
```

If you need that column hidden by default, you can call this function during onLoad. 
Example  http://jsfiddle.net/nynEd/

Comment: Could you explain how to call this function during onLoad?  I need many columns hidden by default.

Answer (score 1):

in your css you should have something like

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
.shown{
    display:block;
}
```

then in your html you should have something like

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th id="th1" class="shown">Name</th>
        <th id="th2" class="shown">Job</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="td1" class="shown">Mike</td>
      <td id="td2" class="shown">Dancer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

you then have to implement a togle method that will change the visibility of the column

```
//id should be passhed as 1, 2, 3 so on...
function togleTable(id){
    if(document.getElementById("th"+id).className == "shown"){
        document.getElementById("th"+id).className = "hidden";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("td"+id).className == "shown"){
        document.getElementById("td"+id).className = "hidden";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("th"+id).className == "hidden"){
        document.getElementById("th"+id).className = "shown";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("td"+id).className == "hidden"){
        document.getElementById("td"+id).className = "shown";
    }
}
```

and then in the compobox onChange() event you should call the togleTable function passing as id the number of the row you want to show/hide

this is a good place to start i think. 
Have fun

**UPDATED**

if you want to have more than one class for your rows dont forget you can also use this:
        document.getElementById('id').classList.add('class');
        document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('class');

Answer (score 1):

There are many way out for this my option is using basic jquery functions like,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="opt1" checked/>col 1
<input type="checkbox" id="opt2"/>col 2

<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Job</th>
  <th id="col1">col 1</th>
  <th id="col2">col 2</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>Dancer</td>
      <td class="data1">data 1</td>
      <td class="data2">data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>​
```

This is your HTML code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#opt1").is(":checked")){
         $("#col1").show();
        $(".data1").show();   
    }else{
         $("#col1").hide();
        $(".data1").hide();
    }
    if($("#opt2").is(":checked")){
         $("#col2").show();
        $(".data2").show();   
    }else{
         $("#col2").hide();
        $(".data2").hide();
    }

    $("#opt1").live('click', function() {
        if($("#opt1").is(":checked")){
         $("#col1").show();
        $(".data1").show();   
    }else{
         $("#col1").hide();
        $(".data1").hide();
    }
    });

    $("#opt2").live('click', function() {
       if($("#opt2").is(":checked")){
         $("#col2").show();
        $(".data2").show();   
    }else{
         $("#col2").hide();
        $(".data2").hide();
    }
    });
});​
```

This is a java-script code.

Please find working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xQnaf/)

Answer (score 0):

The columns which you want to hide should have attribute style="display:none" initially

Comment: Definitely not. Google will strike you down for that. Apply the style with javascript if you don't want any problem with Google/Non-js users.

Comment: I am using this for an intranet database application.  And what do you mean by Google users?  This works in chrome.